# Xamarin.android How to iterator sub keys on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to get sub keys of DataSnapshot when called OnDataChange.
The DataSnapshot.Children type is Java.Lang.IIterable. 
how to use it on Xamarin.Android(native)?

I can't find the example on google.

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
        var Children = snapshot.Children;

        foreach(var child in Children)          // build error
        {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq's `ToEnumerable` to convert the Java `Iterator`:

```
foreach(var item in someJavaIteratable.ToEnumerable())
{
    // do something with item....
}
```

Or use the `Iterator` functions: `HasNext` and `Next`

```
var iter = someJavaIteratable.Iterator();
while (iter.HasNext)
{
    var item = iter.Next;
    // do something with item....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
            var Children = snapshot.Children;
            foreach(var child in Children)          // build error
            {
                String childrenName=childreen.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
            }
    }
```